# Лишнее слово внутри цитаты

Tags: пунктуация, цитаты

Я точно помню, что такая тема была. Но найти не смог, а решение вопроса пунктуации уже вылетело из памяти.

Примеры:

> Дядя рассказчика непрост, он "самых честных — ведь — правил".

> И мы даже прочли "Анну — будь она неладна — Каренину".

В общем, суть, думаю, ясна. Достаточно ли только тире? Не нужны ли дополнительные кавычки? Возможно, нужно многоточие, чтобы показать разрыв цитаты?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Дядя рассказчика непрост, он "самых честных <ведь> правил".**
  Основание: Розенталь "Пунктуация, § 55.5:

  > Если автор или редактор/издатель вставляет в цитату свой текст,
  > поясняющий в ней предложение либо отдельные слова, то этот текст
  > помещают в квадратных (прямых) или угловых скобках (инициалы автора, а
  > также сокращение Ред./Изд. в этом случае не ставят):
  >
  > *…А волоса у неё [русалки] зелёные, что твоя конопля* (Т.)
- **И мы даже прочли "Анну...", будь она неладна, "...Каренину".**
  Основание: Розенталь "Пунктуация", § 50.1, примеч. 1:

  > Особый случай пунктуационного оформления при «разрыве» заключенных в
  > кавычки слов (названий литературных произведений, различных
  > предприятий и т. д.) находим в таком примере: *«Пиковая…» ли это
  > «…дама»?* (реплика собеседника в ответ на утверждение, что
  > представленный текст является отрывком из «Пиковой дамы»).

Comment: Идеально! Спасибо!

Comment: @Третийглаз замечу, что в первом случае я не совсем уверен. Мне думается, что, возможно, вставку надо оформить так: "Дядя рассказчика непрост, он "самых честных (ведь — N.) правил", где N. — сокращение от Nektoid и должно быть заменено инициалом того, кто вставил в цитату своё слово. А в Справочнике издателя и автора есть такой пример: *Печорин говорил, что он «в напрасной борьбе» уже «истощил и жар души своей и постоянство воли»...*

Comment: И за уточнение тоже спасибо!

Comment: Голосую за вопрос и ответ и хочу спросить, почему Вы сомневаетесь в первом случае и предлагаете вариант с круглыми скобками и инициалами?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец потому что у Розенталя речь идёт про авторский текст, который в цитате что-то *поясняет*. А в предложении из вопроса — внутри цитаты не пояснение.

Comment: А, понятно, спасибо.